# UISearchBar в UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Пытаюсь организовать поиск в TableView с помощью SearchBar'a, но почему-то не работает. Вот мой код:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    for (int i = 0; i < _citiesArray.count; i++) {
        City *city = [City new];
        city = [_citiesArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if (_searchBar.text == city.cityName) {
            [filteredArray addObject: city]; 
        }
    }

    if (_citiesArray == nil) {
        [_citiesArray removeAllObjects];
    }
    _fullCitiesArray = filteredArray.copy;

    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: == не работает при сравнении NSString, используйте '[_searchBar.text isEqualToString:city.cityName];'

Comment: спасибо, помогло! знал, но постоянно забываю это )

Comment: не забудьте принять ответ

Answer (score 1):

== не работает при сравнении NSString, используйте `[_searchBar.text isEqualToString:city.cityName];`